# Getting priority messages from Oracle Advanced Queues

Tags: oracle, vb6

Currently I have a piece of code that enqueues and dequeues messages using oracle advanced queues.

What I need to do is first check for messages with a high priority, before getting the others. But I can't seem to do this.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
Public Function GetQMsg(ByRef sMsg, ByRef vMsgId As Variant, Optional lWait As Long = ORAAQ_DQ_NOWAIT) As Long

gobjDB.LastServerErrReset
sMsg = ""

On Error GoTo cmdErr
gobjQ.Wait = lWait     ' ORAAQ_DQ_NOWAIT
gobjQ.Navigation = ORAAQ_DQ_FIRST_MSG ' to refresh snapshot of msgs waiting
'gobjQ.DequeueMode = ORAAQ_DQ_BROWSE
vMsgId = gobjQ.Dequeue()

sMsg = gobjMsg.Value

GetQMsg = 0
GoTo Fin

cmdErr:
If gobjDB.LastServerErr = 25228 Then
    ' no msg available:
    GetQMsg = QUEUE_EMPTY
Else
    GetQMsg = gobjDB.LastServerErr
End If

Fin:
End Function
```

If I add the following line into the code I can see the msg priority, but I can't workout how to return the highest priority messages first.

```
'Debug.Print "Message Priority: " & gobjMsg.Priority
```

I appreciate this is using legacy developments but its fundamental to the bigger application.

So my questions is how to I get the messages returned in priority order ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a queue table you can set up parameter "sort_list".

```
 DBMS_AQADM.CREATE_QUEUE_TABLE (
queue_table        => 'aq.priority_msg', 
sort_list          => 'PRIORITY desc,ENQ_TIME', 
queue_payload_type => 'aq.Message_typ');
```

And queue table will be sorted by priority and enq_time.  Dduring deque you will get the message with highest priority.

Comment: Thanks for your response, does this mean the table will always have the highest priority messages at the top, so my changes to implement this would be in oracle only and my VB6 App will remain unchanged ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a queue in Oracle a number of views are created in the schema that owns the queue. You should be able to query the queue for priority using something like this:

```
SELECT aq.msg_id
FROM   aq$queue_table aq
WHERE aq.priority = <your_priority);
```

Then create a cursor that uses this query and you can modify your procedure to browse or dequeue the desired results.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I'm looking at a way to implement this with minimal code change.